# Simple File I/O in Cuda C++

Tags: c++, cuda

Im working on Cuda C++ right now. But I'm having problems about reading and writing into files with CUDA.

How can I implement file input output processes in Cuda C++?

I wanna read **.obj** files into my Cuda kernel.

What should i do?

Comment: Your question is not very clear to me. Write to/read from files is dealt with as in C/C++. If you want to inline PTX files into your CUDA code, have a look at the `inlinePTX` CUDA SDK sample.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Read the file using ordinary host (C++) file operations. Then transfer the data to the device if you need it there, using ordinary `cudaMalloc` and `cudaMemcpy` operations.

You won't be able to implement file I/O directly in CUDA C++, as there is no API for this and the GPU does not connect directly to the file system. You have to go through the OS for file system services.

While its true that NVIDIA has an adjunct system to CUDA called [GPU Direct Storage](https://docs.nvidia.com/gpudirect-storage/overview-guide/index.html), this is technically not part of CUDA, and is probably not what most people are looking for when it comes to simple file I/O in CUDA.  GPU Direct Storage requires specific system features and setup steps before it can be used, and is well beyond the scope of beginner CUDA usage.

Comment: lol @robert-crovella I will need to get faster at typing to get close to your score it seems! Nice answer, short, concise and to the point.

Answer (score 9):

For your file to get into CUDA memory space you will have to use the CUDA memcpy command after allocating memory for the information (so do a cudaMalloc(your, malloc, params, here) and a cudaMemcpy(your, memcpy, params,here) after you have loaded parsed and stored in memory the file as you would normally in C++.

You could try making a cuda system to access the file directly, but that is a process I would not envy trying to write, and the gain to effort ratio would render it a non-viable venture (apart from a proof of concept excercise).

Hope that helps!:)

Comment: it seems while I was typing Robert Crovella answered the same and beat me to the post!